# How to create multiple node at a same time programatically?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am creating a node via code

```
   function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {   

        if($form_id=='article_node_form'){
            $form['#submit'][] = 'newApp';
        }
}   

functin newApp($form,$form_state){
        $node = new stdClass();
        $node->type = 'application';
        node_object_prepare($node);
        $node->title = $prductData->title;
        $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
        node_save($node);
        }
```

It's creating the application node. I also alter content type node form for article. When I click save button of article content type it's creating my application type node, but it's not creating the article type node. I need the site to create one node create of article type and second application when I save a new article.

Comment: Can you show the whole function your code above is taken from?

Comment: I second that, please provide the whole function including the function's name.

Comment: Please check now.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is because you overriding node variable.

In my opinion the more Drupal way is to use Rules module. There you can create   application node after article is created.

Comment: using rules how its possible.. coz my application content type is creating programatically and I am filling fileds value..